# Overriding Fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch, service-worker

I recently encountered a scenario where it may be advantageous to override fetch.

I have what will be a progressive web app that will have offline functionality.
I've run into the issue where there are dozens of raw fetch calls which I now want to cache the results of in local storage.

```
if cache exists
  invalidate cache if necessary
  if cache valid
    fetch from local storage
  else
    load from network
    save results in local storage
else
  load from network
  save results in local storage
```

One potential issue is that local storage may be insufficient to save cached queries which is why I would look into a pretested solution.

If I can get this to work then I would not have to change any calls to fetch throughout the code.

```
const fetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function() {
 // replaced fetch code here
}
```

Is there anything like this available? Does it seem to be a good idea?

Comment: If you can override `fetch()` why not just make your own `cachingFetch()` (or name it something better) then use that in your code? Yes, you change more code but it's more explicit and thus easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: That sounds like a good use case for a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), which can intercept network requests made from your web app and respond directly from the Cache Storage API as needed.

Comment: cachingFetch() would be a little bit tricky to create as I would have to emulate the object that a call to fetch should return. I haven't seen any information on how to recreate this object.

Comment: service worker cannot use window.localStorage based on the article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API "APIs such as synchronous XHR and Web Storage can't be used inside a service worker".

Comment: @andre_boyce "*cachingFetch() would be a little bit tricky to create as I would have to emulate the object that a call to fetch should return.*" how is that different from your intention of overriding the default `fetch()`? You'd need to emulate the object *anyway* if you want the function to be compatible. Otherwise you break its functionality for anything else that might call `fetch()`. My suggestion is to do the same but *not* override `fetch()` just keep it as a different function.

Comment: Actually that's one possible solution to whay i'm trying to accomplish. I was wondering if there was already a compatible version implemented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function() {
  const obj = { data: 'json data' }; // replace with your own object
  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], { type: 'application/json' });
  const init = { status: 200, statusText: 'success!' };
  const response = new Response(blob, init);
  return response;
}
```